# How to use async parallel for multiple Queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new in javascript.

I have tried to use async.parellel function. 
And get "reviewArr" and return it.

Please see my code.

```
app.get('/api/wherecritique/reviews/search/:author', function(req,res){
   var reviewArr = [];
   Critique.find({author:req.params.autho}, function(err,cris){
       var i =0;
       var f = function(reviewID)
      {
          Review.findOne({id:reviewID}, function(err, review)
          {
               reviewArr.push(review);
          }
      }
      var tasks = {};
      for(var j =0; j<cris.length; j++)
      {
          tasks['func'+j] = f(cris[j].reviewID);
      }
      async.parallel(tasks, function(err, results){
          console.log(results);
          res.json(reviewArr);
      });
  });
});
```

I used mongoose+express+node.js.
Critique, Review are models(mongoose schema).

When I run this code, I get this message.
"task is not a function"

Please help how can i fix this error?
Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not setting up the functions properly. The expected argument are `function()` wrappers with a `callback` argument which gets passed to when the contained async function completes.

You also really just want [`async.map`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) instead of what you are doing, because it's output is an array of the results from the looped calls. So no need to push results into an external variable:

```
app.get('/api/wherecritique/reviews/search/:author', function(req,res) {

  Critique.find({author: req.params.author}, function(err,cris) {

    async.map(
      cris.map( c => c.reviewID ),
      function(id, callback) {
        Review.findOne({ id: id }, callback);
      },
      function(err,results) {
        if (err) throw err; // or something with err
        console.log(results);
        res.json(results);
      }
    );

  });
});
```

But in all honesty you should really be using Promises here rather than import an external library

```
app.get('/api/wherecritique/reviews/search/:author', function(req,res) {

  Critique.find({author: req.params.author}, function(err,cris) {

    Promise.all(
      cris.map( c => Review.findOne({ id: c.reviewID }) )
    ).then( results => {
      console.log(results);
      res.json(results);
    }).catch( e => console.error(e) );

  });

});
```

Or in a more modern way with `async/await`:

```
app.get('/api/wherecritique/reviews/search/:author', async (req,res) => {

  try {       
    let cris = await Critique.find({author: req.params.author});

    let results = Promise.all(
      cris.map( c => Review.findOne({ id: c.reviewID }) )
    );
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

});
```

But in actual reality, this has nothing to do with JavaScript at all, and you really should be using MongoDB features.

Either with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) where supported:

```
app.get('/api/wherecritique/reviews/search/:author', async (req,res) => {

  try {       
    let results = await Critique.aggregate([
      { $match: { author: req.params.author } },
      { $lookup: {
        from: Review.collection.name,
        localField: 'reviewID',
        foreignField: 'id'
        as: 'reviews'
      }},
      { $unwind: '$reviews' }
    ]);

    results = results.map( r => r.reviews );
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

});
```

Or if you don't have that, then simply passing all `id` values to [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
app.get('/api/wherecritique/reviews/search/:author', async (req,res) => {

  try {       
    let cris = await Critique.find({ author: req.params.author });

    let results = await Review.find({ id: { $in: cris.map( c => c.reviewID ) } });
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

});
```

Which means either "one" or "two" actual calls to the database depending on your MongoDB version. No need to loop async calls at all.

---

Finally, it's really not necessary as explained by all the above, but the correct usage of [`async.parallel`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) would be:

```
app.get('/api/wherecritique/reviews/search/:author', (req,res) => {

  Critique.find({author: req.params.author}, (err,cris) => {

    var tasks = cris.map( c => (callback) =>
        Review.findOne({ id: c.reviewID }, callback);
    );

    async.parallel(
      tasks,
      (err,results) => {
        if (err) throw err; // or something
        console.log(results);
        res.json(results);
      }
    )
  });
});
```

Comment: Best answer what i have ever seen.
And also good lecture about async.
Thank you very much.